# Can i use parameters one imports?

Tags: vba, parameters, import, ms-access-2007

What i am trying to do is when i click a button i created i have data imported into a table. This works great right now. What i am wondering if there is a way that when i click this button if i can have a parameter box come up asking for the date that this data is from. once the user types that date in the date will be placed into a column(field) named timestamp.

Does this make sense? I have looked up on how to do this but i just found how to use parameters on querys.

I could really use the help. Thank you for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
'... your existing code
dim dtTimeStamp
dtTimeStamp = InputBox("Please enter a date:")
'may want to validate date
If not isdate(dtTimeStamp) then
   msgbox "Bad date"
end if

doCmd.RunSQL "Update TableX Set TimeStamp = #" & Format(dtTimeStamp, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# where TimeStamp is Null"
```

Comment: Thank you Jimmy for the response. Ill give it a shot. Really quick this could be greedy of me but is there a way that when they put in the date it is connected to a calender so they just pick a date instead of typing it in? Once again thank you for the response.

Comment: In that case, you could add a Date Time Picker control to the form, have them choose the date then skip to doCmd, doCmd.RunSQL "Update TableX Set TimeStamp = #" & DatePicker.value & "# where TimeStamp is Null"

Comment: Perfect sounds like it might work. I have never used a Date Time Picker. Can you please help me find it and explain how to use it please. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is available already in Access 2007.  I believe it is a "format" property on a textbox, like "Show Date Picker"

Comment: Gord i apologize for my lack of knowledge and am asking you how to learn how to use something that you seem to be a pro in. How about help explain the date time picker? I dont think that is off topic for the question. Thank you again!

Comment: Jimmy thank you i found it. Ill try messing around with it. I appreciate the help that you gave. When i come to a conclusion i will post what i have done. If i need further guidance i will post here as well. Thank you very much for answering my questions and putting up with my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @user3321013 That's what everyone is here for!  I don't think the Date picker was part of Access till 2007+ and I primarily use 2003.  When you reach a conclusion, can you post the code?  Always good practice to post what you have so far.

Comment: If you're not too far into this project, consider a different field name because `timestamp` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T) and those can be troublesome.  You could avoid trouble with `time_stamp` as the field name.